# Recommended usage of AppFabric in multi-environment

Tags: caching, appfabric

- Three environments: dev, staging, and production
- Each environment has their own database that may or may not be the same as another environment's database
- There is only one AppFabric cache server

I need to be able to use caching, but at the same time keep the cache separate for each of the three environments.

How are some ways to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named caches and cache regions to fit your different environmental needs. Make the names/regions configurable in a .config file or DB table. Putting cached data in environment-specific caches or regions gives you partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That seems reasonable.  Is there a reason to use a region over a separate cache in my scenario?

Comment: You can clear all objects from a region, but you cannot clear all objects from a cache, so if you need a remove-all type behavior, I'd use regions.